# Application object and Service

Tags: android, service

I know that is possible to start a service with no activities, ... My question is: if I start the service as Foreground (calling startForegorund()), is the application object always instantiated?

Or is it possible that getApplication() == null in some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `Application` is created whenever your app is running regardless if it's activity, foreground or background service. So you shouldn't get `null` when call `getApplication`.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but I've got a "strange" behaviour in my app, using a service, that make me think something is going very wrong with my Application/Activities/Service management. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can post example of your code where you have "strange" behaviour, may be somebody can help with it.

Comment: It's a little complex to put here some code. I say that when I try to close the application, finishing alla activities, stopping service and calling System.exit(0), sometime I found that the application is still running and if I launch it from the android desktop, it crashes. It seems that some activities are not closed... I've specialized the Application object and I think there's a problem here: probably I'm using the singleton in the wrong way. On http://developer.android.com they say that normally there's no need to sub-class the application object and I will follow this suggestion.